# How to use an html method of affecting the legend - highcharts / highslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highslide

I would like to use html in the body of the page to be able to affect the filters of the chart. My chart  legend is modified slightly to be able to handle the filtering in a different way (inverted), so I would like this behaviour to stay intact.

I found an example that did this...

```
function(chart){
    $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
        $('<li id="legendlinkstyle" style="color: '+serie.color+'">'+serie.name+'</li>').click(function(){
            serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
        }).appendTo('#legend')
    })
}
```

but it does not allow me to edit the text of the links, nor do things like affect the hover color, etc which I would like to do. In addition, I would like the flexibility to do things like add headers for each category of filter names like the below picture.

[image]

Is there a way to do add something in the javascript, and then somehow in the html body to do something like this.... (when you click it, it toggles a filter in the legend)

```
<a href="functionhere();">CUSTOMIZE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts has a quite powerful javascript API, you can really do a lot with it. However code above does exactly what you need, you just have to improve it a little bit. Take a look at another (I think a bit more advanced) example:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        series: [{
            id: 'earnings-above',
            name: 'above',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            id: 'earnings-inline',
            name: 'inline',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            id: 'earnings-below',
            name: 'below',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    }, function (chart) {

      // bind events to your own custom legend
      $('#my-legend').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
        var el = e.target,
            id = el.getAttribute('data-id'),
            series = chart.get(id);

        series.setVisible(!series.visible);
      });
    });
});
```

Here is related HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<div id="my-legend">
  <strong>Earnings:</strong>
  <button data-id="earnings-above">above</button>
  <button data-id="earnings-inline">inline</button>
  <button data-id="earnings-below">below</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the legend is rendered separately and we just bind it to Highcharts by storing series ids in "data-id" attribute.

Here you can find a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bk7Au/